# Limiting query in MS Access in PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I`m rewriting an application that use MS Access as the database.

I was able to connect and fetch data from tables, but how can I apply limit and offset like `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 10 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tablename

[Similar thread(no offset allowed in access)](http://forums.devshed.com/database-management-46/limit-and-offset-in-ms-access-was-ms-access-help-333247.html)

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tablename works but how can i get the next set like from 11-20

Comment: [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900635/how-do-i-implement-pagination-in-sql-for-ms-access)

Comment: Actually offset clause is not supported by access as stated [here](http://forums.devshed.com/database-management-46/limit-and-offset-in-ms-access-was-ms-access-help-333247.html) too. But still you may apply a logic to achieve it as given in the link above. Sorry i rarely use access, so can't be of much help.

Answer (score 1):

In Access the syntax is `TOP n`;

```
select top 10 * from tablename
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, what will happen during pagination? because i still need the offset for pagination

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900635/how-do-i-implement-pagination-in-sql-for-ms-access

Answer (score 0):

http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#ex8 is much better solution. You can modify it a bit to suit your needs. By default it return in html table, which can be modified to get field names and specific number of rows as array