# Creating a MS Access query with page number?

Tags: java, mysql, database, ms-access

> Duplicate of [Limiting query in MS Access in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355886/limiting-query-in-ms-access-in-php)

I know the query of mysql in php with both limit and page number.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tname WHERE year='$y' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $pg, $limit");
```

Here $pg is page number and $limit is the number of records per page.

Now i want to run the same query with MS Access Database with Java Platform.

I found that the keyword `limit` cannot be used in ms access, so found `Top` keyword.

So my final working query is

```
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery("SELECT top 100 * FROM tname WHERE year='$y' ORDER BY date DESC");
```

I want to include the page number in the ms access query... How can i do this ???
My database table has approx 3000 rows.

I want a query like the above mysql query with page number and limit which works in ms access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do MS Access database paging + search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914637/how-to-do-ms-access-database-paging-search)

Answer (score 0):

Access has no "easy" built-in support for paging like MySQL's `LIMIT`, but it's possible anyway.
Take a look at this:
[How to do MS Access database paging + search?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916791/6884)