# SQL selecting IN given set desnt get narrowed down

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a table with emails (called Mails) and I want to mark particular messages as assigned to different teams of workers (eg. team01, team02 etc). The msg<->team relations are kept in another table (called MailAssignments). I'm trying to get messages which are marked as being for just one team (let's say team01) and the message ID should be less than a specified value so that the set of messages is narrowed down to, lets say, 10.

I've got the below query but it always shows ALL messages assigned to the team isntead of showing only the ones with msgId < specified.

What is wrong with my query?

```
string queryGetMails =
"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Mails WHERE msgId IN (SELECT msgId FROM MailAssignments WHERE (forTeam='team01') AND (msgId < ?) )";
```

I've also tried this (and the result is the same) :/

```
"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Mails WHERE (msgId<?) AND (msgId IN (SELECT msgId FROM MailAssignments WHERE forTeam='team01' ) )";
```

Comment: Is your end goal to implement pagination? Showing 10 messages at a time?

Comment: @Patrick, yes, exactly. I want to display only 10 messages at a time and only those which are assigned to the given team.

Comment: OK, once you get your query working properly, have a look at this SO post. It will give you an idea on how to page the results. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900635/how-do-i-implement-pagination-in-sql-for-ms-access

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insist with subqueries and in clause when it seems that you have a clear join between the two tables? Have you tried this?

```
SELECT TOP 10 Mails.* 
FROM Mails left join 
MailAssignments On Mails.msgID = MailAssignments.msgID 
WHERE Mails.msgId < ? AND MailAssignments.forTeam = 'team01'
```

Comment: Gives an index out of range exception: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: msgId` when trying to get the column id for a specified column name in the C# code: `int idCol = myReader.GetOrdinal("msgId");`

Comment: Well could you show the code that calls this query with the offending line? However that seems to be another problem. If you place the query in access and run, do you get the expected results?

Comment: The OutOfRangeException may be because msgID is ambiguous... it exists in MailAssignments and Mails. If you explicitly define the fields you want returned in the select, you'll know exactly what to query your reader for.

Comment: @Patrick, Right, always better to be explicit, or simply Mail.*. Answer updated

Comment: @Steve, the whole code is too long to paste it here because it retrieves all email details (sender, recipients, subject, body etc) but generally it's just: 1. the sql query defined. 2. then `myConnection.Open();` and `ExecuteReader();` 3. then getting column numbers `myReader.GetOrdinal("msgId");` 4. and then the loop with `myReader.Read()` which reads all the data row by row. And I get the exception when the first column number is checked.

Comment: @Patrick, how do I explicitly define the fields? I thought I did! :/

Comment: OleDbDataReader.GetOrdinal as from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getordinal.aspx) docs require the name of a columns. If that column doesn't exist you get the IndexOutOfRangeException. So I think that the Mail.* or 'select column1. column2, etc' as suggested by @Patrick resolves this problem

Comment: I guess it means that the msgId column is not returned for me. But I do have the `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Mails...` in the beginning of the query - to take all fields from each row

Comment: When typing `SELECT TOP 10 Mail.* FROM Mails...` I get the exception `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Jet database engine does not recognize 'Mail.*' as a valid field name or expression.`

Comment: `SELECT TOP 10 Mails.* FROM Mails` (There was nothing aliased as `Mail`.)

Comment: @ValCool Just some thoughts. First make sure the query works in access/mysql/phpmyadmin or wherever. Then, once the query is returning something reasonable, move it to the C# code, so you know what columns you can expect. Also, make sure that you had at least one result, and that none of your msgID cells are empty. (I assume that's the Primary Key?)