# Translate query from SQL Server to Access 2000

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've an Access 2000 `.mdb` file. I have this query in the same database but on SQL Server. The query works fine in SQL Server, but in Access I get an error; I supposed it is due to `ROW_NUMBER()`.

I can't use vba to make this query because I have to run it with Odbc driver.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cognome,nome ASC) AS RowID
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              (a.ID_PAZIENTE) AS codice,
              a.NOME AS nome,
              a.COGNOME AS cognome,
              a.TITOLO AS titolo,
              a.TELEFONOABITAZIONE AS tel,
              a.TELEFONOUFFICIO AS uff,
              a.FAX AS cell,
              a.E_MAIL AS email,
              a.SESSO AS sesso
          FROM 
              PAZIENTI AS a
          WHERE 1 = 1) AS AnagraficheDistinct
    ) AS Anagrafiche
WHERE 
    RowID >= 1 AND RowID <= 25
ORDER BY 
    cognome, nome ASC;
```

And this is the error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in expression of query: "ROW_NUMBER()
>   OVER (ORDER BY cognome,nome ASC)

I tried to convert the query following online documentation and this is what I made:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
  SELECT Top 10
  *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 p.ID_PAZIENTE,p.cognome,p.nome
   FROM PAZIENTI p   
   ORDER BY p.cognome ASC,p.nome ASC
   ) AS sub1
   ORDER BY sub1.cognome DESC,sub1.nome DESC
   ) AS anagrafiche
   ORDER BY  p.cognome ASC,p.nome ASC
```

Unfortunately this query returns strange results. Changing the start index ([How do I implement pagination in SQL for MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900635/how-do-i-implement-pagination-in-sql-for-ms-access)), sometimes return 10 results (the page size), sometimes 12 based on the start index (startpos + page size).

I'm doing something wrong or this thing in no possible with Access without VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following. RowNumber() is not available in Access SQL but can possibly be replicated with a rank by name using subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
             a.ID_PAZIENTE AS codice, 
             a.NOME AS nome, 
             a.COGNOME AS cognome, 
             a.TITOLO AS titolo, 
             a.TELEFONOABITAZIONE AS tel, 
             a.TELEFONOUFFICIO AS uff, 
             a.FAX AS cell, 
             a.E_MAIL AS email, 
             a.SESSO AS sesso,
             (SELECT count(*)
              FROM PAZIENTI As b
              WHERE b.cognome <= a.cognome 
                AND b.nome <= a.nome) As RowID
   FROM PAZIENTI AS a) AS AnagraficheDistinct 
   ) AS Anagrafiche 
WHERE RowID >= 1 AND RowID <= 25 
ORDER BY cognome, nome;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Query in MS-Access is logically completely different from the SQL-Server-Query.

The first one gives you the first 25 rows ordered by `cognome,nome`.
The Access-Query gives you the last 10 Rows from the first 20 Rows in the specified order.

In Access there is no built-in-Function such as ROW_NUMBER. And because you are using two fields as ordering criteria for the ROW_NUMBER (cognome, nome) the usage of a Count(*) Subquery doesn't work.

But I have instead built a type of RANK-Function in Access and maybe that work's for you. But, it may give also more rows back as you specify for one pagesize, if the number of rows with the same value in `cognome` is greater than the pagesize. In this query it is important, that only `cognome` is part of the Count(*) subquery.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
  SELECT codice, cognome, nome, titolo, tel, uff, cell, email
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID_PAZIENTE AS codice, a.COGNOME AS cognome, 
                    a.NOME AS nome, a.TITOLO AS titolo, 
                    a.TELEFONOABITAZIONE AS tel, a.TELEFONOUFFICIO AS uff,  
                    a.FAX AS cell, a.E_MAIL AS email, a.SESSO AS sesso, 
                    (SELECT Count(*) FROM PAZIENTI AS temp 
                     WHERE temp.cognome < a.cognome
                    ) + 1 AS Rank
    FROM PAZIENTI AS a
  ) AS psub
WHERE Rank >= 1 AND Rank <= 5
ORDER BY Rank
) p
ORDER BY cognome, nome
```

If that doesn't help you, I think, you will need a VBA-Function. But here it is critical to reset the counter before every query.

An other Option is using a Pass-Through-Query and send the first query directly to SQL-Server. You have to specify the odbc-Connectionstring in the Query-Object in Access.

Comment: Good answer! Just add Rank in the outer derived table so it can be used in `WHERE` of outside table. You can even remove outside table `p` as it is no longer needed since RowID is calculated in innermost subquery. Let's see what OP thinks.

Comment: Thanks Parfait. I think the Outer Query with the seperate ORDER BY is needed, when there is more than one row with the same value for cognome. In thas case the rank-value will be the same and there is no specific order unless I specify an explicit ORDER BY as last step