# VBA DAvg() in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, statistics

I'm using the DAvg function in Access. The function has the following structure:

```
DAvg ( expr , domain , [criteria] )
```

My problem is: I don't want the average of all the field. I want the average in blocks of 96 rows.

So first I wanna the average of the first 96 records, then from 96 to 192 and so on...

I know I have to use the criteria field, but I have no clue of how to do this.
Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer when there is no description of the table.   You will probably need to query the table.  This would be a good place to start: [How do I implement pagination in SQL for MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900635/how-do-i-implement-pagination-in-sql-for-ms-access)

Comment: It's a table with just numbers... its a common table. My only problem is to implement in this criteria.

Comment: If the table is auto incremented and there are no missing numbers then it will be fairly simple otherwise you will have to use a paginator pattern to get the desired results.

Comment: Lets say is an auto incremented table Thomas, I could add a vector with 1, 2, 3, 4... at the first column of the table. How could the function be used?

Comment: In VBA you create a loop `For n = 1 to DCount("*", domain) Step 96` and then Avg ( expr , domain , "ID>=" & n & " AND ID<=" & n +96)

Comment: In a query you'd need a calculated field `Int(ID/9) + 1 As PageNum`  and then DAvg ( expr , domain , "PageNum  =" & PageNum  )`

Answer (score 0):

In a query, you would use the native `Avg`, like:

```
Select 
    Int([ID] / 96) As [Block],
    Avg([YourFieldName]) As Average
From
    YourTable
Group By
    Int([ID] / 96)
```